# How to get rid of the side lines when scale in css?

Tags: css

[image]

I am using spring(react) for this animation. I even used framer motion. both getting the same type of effect when trying to scale shape.

I short-term scaling shape with scale.

Does anyone ever faced this type of issue in CSS??

this is the demo:= https://vfrw4.csb.app/

Comment: Have you tried adding `will-change: transform;` to the elements that are scaling? When Javascript takes care of transformations sometimes it messes up how the browser paints it.